# Initialize two different tables with a single AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm trying to render two different tables but with a single `AJAX` call.

How to initialize two different tables but using the same source of `JSON` data? 
The only different of these two tables is that I filter the rows by a specific key in `JSON`.

Currently my code looks like this.

```
var t = $('#adminKeysTable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                "url": getKeysById,
                "dataSrc": function(json) {
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i=0;i<json.keys.length;i++) {
                        if (json.keys[i].privileges == '32') 
                            rows.push(json.keys[i]);
                            allAdminKeys.push(json.keys[i].key);
                    }
                    return rows;
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": null },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "key" },
                { "data": null }
            ]               
        } );

var tt = $('#apiAccessKeyTable').DataTable( {
            "ajax": {
                "url": getKeysById,
                "dataSrc": function(json) {
                    var rows = [];
                    for (var i=0;i<json.keys.length;i++) {
                        if (json.keys[i].privileges != '32') 
                            rows.push(json.keys[i]);
                    }
                    return rows;
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": null }, 
                { "data": "name", "className": "editable" }, 
                { "data": "key" }, 
                { "data": "externalUser", "className": "editable" }, 
                { "data": "privilegesArray", "className": "edit-privileges" },
                { "data": null }, 
                { "data": null } 
            ]
        } );
```

The issue with my current code is that it tends to take longer time to load the second table after the first one has done loading. I'm assuming that's because I'm making two `AJAX` calls at the same time?

I'm new to `AJAX`. So not sure how to make only one call to the `GET` request, and use that `JSON` data to initialize two separate tables.

Appreciate if someone can guide me. Thanks.

Comment: simply make one `ajax` request out of the `dataTable` init code, store that response in a variable, then call 2 different `dataTable` with that same data

Comment: first make a ajax call when data is return just simply bind to Datatable.

Comment: @Towkir Can you post an example of how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Taking different into consideration, once you get data, you can store the data to the different variable and pass the data view to likewise you're passing.

```
var tt = $('#apiAccessKeyTable').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": getKeysById,
            "dataSrc": function(json) {
                var t1rows = [];
                var t2rows = [];
                for (var i=0;i<json.keys.length;i++) {
                    if (json.keys[i].privileges != '32') {
                        t1rows.push(json.keys[i]); // Changed section
                    } else {
                        t2rows.push(json.keys[i]); // changed section
                    }

                }
                return rows;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": null }, 
            { "data": "name", "className": "editable" }, 
            { "data": "key" }, 
            { "data": "externalUser", "className": "editable" }, 
            { "data": "privilegesArray", "className": "edit-privileges" },
            { "data": null }, 
            { "data": null } 
        ]
    } );
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I seriously have no experience with that `DataTable` method from jQuery. But you could do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: getKeysById,
     success: function(json) {
         var t1rows = [];
         var t2rows = [];

         for (var i = 0; i < json.keys.length; i++) {
             if (json.keys[i].privileges != '32') {
                 t1rows.push(json.keys[i]); // Changed section
             }
             else {
                 t2rows.push(json.keys[i]); // changed section
             }
          }
          callback(t1rows, t2rows);
      }
});


var callback = function(data1, data2){
    $('#apiAccessKeyTable').DataTable({columns: []}); //add your data here: t1rows
    $('#adminKeysTable').DataTable({columns: []}); //add your data here: t2rows;
}
```

You first execute a standalone ajax call and render your tables in the success handler.

You should look at how to add a data from that jQuery datatable that didnt come from an internal ajax request. I'm assuming it'll be relatively easy. Something like:

```
var callback = function(data1, data2){
$('#adminKeysTable').DataTable({
    dataSrc: data1,
    columns: []
});

$('#apiAccessKeyTable').DataTable({
    dataSrc: data2,
    columns: []
});
}
```

?

This can be even further simplified but for the sake of being relatively similar to your code I'm gonna leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

You do 1 ajax call, split data based on condition and load Datatable with respective JSON

Something like this

```
var t1rows = [];
var t2rows = [];


function splitData(){

    $.ajax({
         url: getKeysById,
         success: function(json) {
         for (var i=0; i < json.keys.length ; i++) {
             if (json.keys[i].privileges != '32') {
                 t1rows.push(json.keys[i]); // Changed section
             }
             else {
                 t2rows.push(json.keys[i]); // changed section
             }
          }
          // load Datatables
        loadDatatable1();
        loadDatatable2();


          }
    });
}


function loadDatatable1(){

    $('#apiAccessKeyTable').dataTable({
        data: t1rows,
        columns: [
            { data: 'userID' },
            { data: 'userName' }
        ]
    });
}


function loadDatatable2(){

    $('#adminKeysTable').dataTable({
        data: t2rows,
        columns: [
            { data: 'userID' },
            { data: 'userName' }
        ]
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have modified a fiddle from answer of this [Datatable - Insert JSON data to the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478587/datatable-insert-json-data-to-the-table)

You can try something like in this fiddle

`https://jsfiddle.net/gx3ktawn/311/`

**HTML**

```
<button id="getResults">Get Results</button>
<table id="my_logs"></table>
<table id="my_logs2"></table>
```

**Script**

```
var myTable = $('#my_logs').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "data": [],
    "columns": [{
        "title": "Date",
        "data": "log_time"
    }, {
        "title": "User Name",
        "data": "user_name"

    }, {
        "title": "Class",
        "data": "class_name"

    }, {
        "title": "Function",
        "data": "class_function"

    }, {
        "title": "Action",
        "data": "action_title"

    }, {
        "title": "Description",
        "data": "action_description"

    }]
});
var myTable2 = $('#my_logs2').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "lengthChange": true,
    "searching": true,
    "ordering": true,
    "info": true,
    "autoWidth": true,
    "data": [],
    "columns": [{
        "title": "Date",
        "data": "log_time"
    },  {
        "title": "Class",
        "data": "class_name"

    }, {
        "title": "Function",
        "data": "class_function"

    }, {
        "title": "Description",
        "data": "action_description"

    }]
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getResults").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/ml2k2',
            success: function(logs) {
                myTable.clear();
                $.each(logs, function(index, value) {
                    myTable.row.add(value);
                });
                myTable.draw();
        myTable2.clear();
                $.each(logs, function(index, value) {
                    myTable2.row.add(value);
                });
                myTable2.draw();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
                alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```